# decrypt the response from aws KMS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

How to obtain my decryted result from KMS response. Below is the response from KMS and here how can I obtain my result from the plaintext.

below result is json.stringify(kmsresponse). below presented is a sample value.

```
{
"$metadata": {
    "httpStatusCode": 200,
    "requestId": "",
    "attempts": 1,
    "totalRetryDelay": 0
},
"EncryptionAlgorithm": "SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT",
"KeyId": "",
"Plaintext": {
    "0": 01,
    "1": 01,
    "2": 02,
    "3": 03,
    "4": 04,
    "5": 05,
    "6": 06,
    "7": 06,
    "8": 55,
    "9": 100,
    "10": 10,
    "11": 54,
    "12": 99,
    "13": 98,
    "14": 14,
    "15": 15,
    "16": 16,
    "17": 17,
    "18": 18,
    "19": 19
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

To decode the response you just need to use the `Buffer` class. Assuming the response from the `decrypt` call is in a variable called `decryptResponse` it would look something like this:

```js
    if (Buffer.isBuffer(decryptResponse.Plaintext)) {
      const decrypted = Buffer.from(decryptResponse.Plaintext).toString();

      const credential = JSON.parse(decrypted) as Credential;
      return credential;
    }
    else {
      throw new Error('Decrypt response was not a buffer');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the KSM service, you can encrypt and decrypt data. Based on your question, you seem to be asking how you can get decrypted data from the **decrypt** operation.

Like most AWS Services, you can get the data from the given response object. Here is an example that shows encrypting and decrypting data in Java. You can port this to JavaScript  using the AWS SDK for JavaScript. However, the Java example will give you a starting point.

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.SdkBytes;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.KmsClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.model.EncryptRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.model.EncryptResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.model.KmsException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.model.DecryptRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.model.DecryptResponse;
// snippet-end:[kms.java2_encrypt_data.import]

public class EncryptDataKey {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String USAGE = "\n" +
                "Usage:\n" +
                "    EncryptDataKey <keyId> \n\n" +
                "Where:\n" +
                "    keyId - a key id value to use to encrypt/decrypt the data (for example, xxxxxbcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab). \n\n" ;

        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println(USAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String keyId = args[0];
        Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
        KmsClient kmsClient = KmsClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        SdkBytes encryData = encryptData(kmsClient, keyId);
        decryptData(kmsClient, encryData, keyId);
        System.out.println("Done");
        kmsClient.close();
    }

     // snippet-start:[kms.java2_encrypt_data.main]
     public static SdkBytes encryptData(KmsClient kmsClient, String keyId) {

         try {
             SdkBytes myBytes = SdkBytes.fromByteArray(new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0});

             EncryptRequest encryptRequest = EncryptRequest.builder()
                     .keyId(keyId)
                     .plaintext(myBytes)
                     .build();

             EncryptResponse response = kmsClient.encrypt(encryptRequest);
             String algorithm = response.encryptionAlgorithm().toString();
             System.out.println("The encryption algorithm is " + algorithm);

             // Get the encrypted data
             SdkBytes encryptedData = response.ciphertextBlob();
             return encryptedData;
         } catch (KmsException e) {
             System.err.println(e.getMessage());
             System.exit(1);
         }
         return null;
     }
    // snippet-end:[kms.java2_encrypt_data.main]

    // snippet-start:[kms.java2_decrypt_data.main]
    public static void decryptData(KmsClient kmsClient, SdkBytes encryptedData, String keyId) {

    try {
         DecryptRequest decryptRequest = DecryptRequest.builder()
                 .ciphertextBlob(encryptedData)
                 .keyId(keyId)
                 .build();

            DecryptResponse decryptResponse = kmsClient.decrypt(decryptRequest);
            decryptResponse.plaintext();

    } catch (KmsException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
  }
    // snippet-end:[kms.java2_decrypt_data.main]
}
```